# Convert Pyspark dataframe column to dict without RDD conversion

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe where columns are integers:

```
MYCOLUMN:
1
1
2
5
5
5
6
```

The goal is to get the output equivalent to `collections.Counter([1,1,2,5,5,5,6])`. I can achieve the desired result by transforming the column to RDD, calling collect and the Counter, but this is rather slow for large data frames.

Is there a better approach that uses dataframes that can achieve the same result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe `groupby` and `count` is similar to what you need. Here is my solution to count each number using dataframe. I'm not sure if this is going to be faster than using RDD or not.

```
# toy example
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame([1, 1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 6], columns=['MYCOLUMN']))

df_count = df.groupby('MYCOLUMN').count().sort('MYCOLUMN')
```

**Output** from `df_count.show()`

```
+--------+-----+
|MYCOLUMN|count|
+--------+-----+
|       1|    2|
|       2|    1|
|       5|    3|
|       6|    1|
+--------+-----+
```

Now, you can turn to dictionary like `Counter` using `rdd`

```
dict(df_count.rdd.map(lambda x: (x['MYCOLUMN'], x['count'])).collect())
```

This will give output as `{1: 2, 2: 1, 5: 3, 6: 1}`

Comment: The desired output is a dictionary. Similar to what is generated with collections.Counter([1,1,2,5,5,5,6]).

Comment: I updated the solution. Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: This calls RDD, like my original approach. I was wondering if this can be achieved without conversion to RDD. I assume it is not.

Comment: But the superior here is you calculate the count dataframe before  converting to `rdd`. I assume (not tested) that this could be a little faster than converting all dataframe to rdd and doing count.